# Problema com retorno de requisição AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring

Estou fazendo uma requisição em ajax porem o resultado dela não atualiza, é como se ficasse em algum tipo de cookie.

```html
function AtualizaTotalItensNota(idFornec) {
   
   
   $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     dataType: "text",
     url: "/sistema/compras/entrada/getitens/" + idFornec,
     success: function (result) {
    $("#totalitens").text(result)
     }
 });
   
}
```

Se eu fizer a requisição manualmente pelo navegador (direto na barra de endereço) ela atualiza, porem usando a função JS o valor ficar sempre o mesmo.

Alguém sabe me dizer o que pode ser?

Comment: E quando você chama a função 'AtualizaTotalItensNota'?

Comment: seria após deletar um item da nota, é dentro de outra requisição ajax:

Comment: o que vem em result? 
success: function (result) {
                //coloque um console.log(result) aqui e mostra, por favor.
    $("#totalitens").text(result)
     }

Comment: Então, vem o valor total de itens da nota, porem eu deleto o item e se eu fizer a requisição manualmente pela barra do navegador o item é atualizado normalmente.
Ja fiz um teste de alert, ele entra na função, porem o valor que volta no result é sempre o ultimo da requisição que fiz direto pela barra do navegador.

Comment: Poste o trecho do código inteiro, é mais fácil de ajudar assim...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que acontece é realmente cache, o que você pode fazer é mandar um parâmetro randômico na sua requisição, ou desabilitar o cache na requisição.
Para desabilitar o cache é só fazer dessa forma:

```
function AtualizaTotalItensNota(idFornec) {


   $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: "GET",            
        dataType: "text",
        url: "/sistema/compras/entrada/getitens/" + idFornec,
        success: function (result) {
          $("#totalitens").text(result)
        }
    });

}
```

Você pode verificar que adicionei o `cache: false,` na requisição

Comment: Muito obrigado, resolvel =D

Answer (score 0):

Na documentação do jquery está descrito que o cacheamento de requisições é ativado por padrão EXCETO para os tipos 'script' e 'jsonp'

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Acrescentando a opção cache:false deve resolver o problema